# How to programmatically check if an expression is r-value or l-value in C (possibly non-standard)

Tags: c, gcc, c-preprocessor, lvalue, rvalue

Suppose I would like to write a preprocessor macro which would have a conditional branch inside built on whether an argument to that macro is l-value or r-value. Is that achievable with C (not C++, not C11), possibly with GCC extensions?

Comment: @StoryTeller I am asking about C, not C++.

Comment: Gotcha, should have read more carefully

Comment: I don't think this is possible

Comment: Do you wanna check it in compile time?

Comment: Why do you say "C, ... not C11"? C11 *is* C.

Comment: @FelipeLavratti I am not sure it would be possible otherwise.

Comment: @KeithThompson by that I mean C without C11 extensions.

Comment: C11 is not "extensions", it is the current version of the language. If you mean "C99 only", say so.

Comment: What do you want it for?

Comment: It's fundamentally impossible with just the preprocessor. gcc/clang probably do not have an extension for it.

Comment: @PSkocik I was curious if I could place such guard to conditionally assign a value in code like this: https://github.com/WojciechMigda/CSL/blob/master/src/move_ptr.h#L40

Comment: @WojciechMigda I don't believe such a check is available in modern compilers, but maybe, if your macro intends to modify, it should take a pointer instead of a value, hoping it's an lvalue.